# User is not in passwd and shadow file but when getent passwd user it shows

Tags: password, passwd, useradd

User is not in /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow file but when I "getent passwd userSec" it shows the account details.

```
[root@myServer systemadmin]# getent passwd userSec
userSec:sdfdgfdsge34gfdsgfdsgfdsgwerwrewd.:709:709:userSec_Account:/home/userSec:/bin/bash
[root@myServer systemadmin]# cat /etc/passwd | grep userSec
[root@myServer systemadmin]# cat /etc/shadow | grep userSec
```

Tried deleting and adding the user but still no luck.

```
[root@myServer systemadmin]# sudo /usr/sbin/userdel -r userSec
userdel: error deleting password entry
userdel: error deleting shadow password entry
userdel: error removing directory /home/userSec
[root@myServer systemadmin]# /usr/sbin/useradd -d /home/userSec -m -s /bin/bash userSec
useradd: user userSec exists
```

Comment: Are you using by any chance an ldap server for authentication? If nothing else you can look into the files directly. `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group` and `/etc/shadow` and see if it is actually in there. Don't grep, actually look inside it, maybe something is left somewhere in reference.

Comment: You can check which lookups you use with `egrep '^shadow|^passwd' /etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: reboot and try again.

Comment: I honestly don't know. But I don't think it has because this is the only account that has issue. Thank You.

Comment: Fix:
> Add userSec in /etc/passwd manually
> did pwconv to sync it with /etc/shadow
> did passwd userSec, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because it might take time to sync, what worked for me was try deleting the user from client and try getent again)) and if everything is connected to dns, don't forget to add ldap to dns on poweradmin, and also try `ifdown enp0s3 && ifup enp0s3`